# file_put_contents not working on server

Tags: php, html, linux, fedora

this simple code create a file, when page is refreshed but it is not working.

```
<?php
    $fileName="test1.html";
    $content="<h1>header</h1>";
    file_put_contents($fileName,$content);
?>
```

From what I can see the user has all the privileges needed to create a file

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 admin1 root         13 Jul 10 22:35 html -> /var/www/html
```

any ideas of what might be preventing creation of the file?

Comment: So php runs under `admin1`?

Comment: What is the error displayed?

Comment: @FirstOne  all the php are owned by user Admin1-rw-r--r--. 1 admin1 root       77 Jul 24 16:04 file.html
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin1 Ian    241 Jul 21 16:37 form_email.php
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin1 Ian    725 Jul 23 18:31 forms_basics.php
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin1 Ian    215 Jul 21 22:11 form_script.php
-rw-rw-r--. 1 admin1 Ian    245 Jul 21 21:55 helloworld2.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 admin1 Ian    114 Jul 24 17:30 helloworld.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 admin1 root       18 Jul 20 13:07 include.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 admin1 Ian    383 Jul 15 11:31 index.html [/CODE]

Comment: @Drakes no error displayed when I refresh the browser

Comment: It is probably SELinux. You don't want to allow your scripts to write anywhere all over your document root. What are the permissions of ` /var/www/html` (`ls -ldZ  /var/www/html`). Does it work with SELinux in permissive?

Comment: @Jakuje command  (ls -ldZ /var/www/html) yields  (
drwxr-xr-x. 2 admin1 Ian system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 274 Jul 24 17:36 /var/www/html).  still does not work with Selinux permissive (setenforce 0)

Answer (score 0):

Your `html` is symlink to `/var/www/html`:

```
ls -ldZ /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x. 2 admin1 brahim system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 274 Jul 24 17:36 /var/www/html
```

You don't need the write permission for that symlink, but for the target of the symlink.

Also it is not about **you** having the permissions, but the user which is running the `apache` web server (usually `www-data`, `apache` on Fedora) needs these permissions.

Also giving all users the permissions to write to your web directory is a bad idea, so lets try this one:

1. Create a subdirectory in `/var/www/html` called `data`:

   ```
   mkdir /var/www/html/data
   ```
2. Give it writable permissions for the `apache` user:

   ```
   chown apache:root /var/www/html/data
   chmod 700 /var/www/html/data
   ```
3. Modify your script to write into this directory:

   ```
   $fileName="data/test1.html";
   ```

Comment: @jakue I get error message 
chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:root’  I think I may have deleted the user www-data by mistake. I can not find this user in  cat /etc/passwd  :(

Comment: If you delete system users don't be surprised things don't work for you. Starting with a clean install should probably move you forward.

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect the `apache` user. `www-data` is used on Debian. Using `apache` user should do the job.

Comment: @ jakuje top star! it worked. Thank you for your help. I guess security wise..this is a good practise ?

Comment: Writing into separate directory is certainly better than writing in document root. Given that you write just this content, it is ok. If you process further user input, you should take more care, but it would take more than to the comment to discuss this.